# Prefill email content with NSButton hyperlink

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, nsbutton

I was wondering how I could, or if it's even possible to, prefill an email message's content when you click an NSButton, so far I open up the default email client but I want to prefill the body of the email and was wondering how I'd do that. Below is the current code:

```
-(IBAction)openEmail:(id)sender {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:domain@domain.com"]];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The "mailto" URI scheme supports this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than forcing a user out of your app, why don't you use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to present the standard message composition window?

MFMailComposeViewController conveniently also has methods to set the message body and just about anything else you would like.

UPDATE: Oops, I misread "NSButton" as "UIButton" - what I wrote above only applies to iOS.  Using the mailto: additions is the correct approach AFAIK on OS X.

Comment: Isn't that just for iOS, I'm not making an iOS app - it's a Mac app.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, my mistake.  I updated my "answer" a minute ago to reflect that realization right after I posted.